# Conversion character, and fgets() function didn't work as expected

Tags: c

I was trying to write a code to find the size of data types and here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    printf("Choose one of the following types to get the relevant storage size\n(int, float, double, short, long, char: ");

    char mytype1[7] = "";
    char mytype2[4] = "int";
    char mytype3[7] = "double";
    char mytype4[6] = "short";
    char mytype5[5] = "long";
    char mytype6[5] = "char";
    char mytype7[6] = "float";
    scanf("%s", mytype1);
    // fgets(mytype1, 7, stdin);

    if (strcmp(mytype1, mytype2) ==0){
        printf("The 'int' variable size is %lu\n", sizeof(int));
    } else if (strcmp(mytype1, mytype3) ==0){
        printf("The 'double' variable size is %lu\n", sizeof(double));
    } else if (strcmp(mytype1, mytype4) ==0){
        printf("The 'short' variable size is %lu\n", sizeof(short));
    } else if (strcmp(mytype1, mytype5) ==0){
        printf("The 'long' variable size is %lu\n", sizeof(long));
    } else if (strcmp(mytype1, mytype6) ==0){
        printf("The 'char' variable size is %lu\n", sizeof(char));

    } else if (strcmp(mytype1, mytype7) ==0){
        printf("the 'float' variable size is %lu\n", sizeof(float));

    } else {
        printf("incorrect choice\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

my questions are:

1. why Xcode didn't accept any conversion character except %lu, for instance I have tried the '%d' with the 'int' statement but I am getting warning that the argument has type 'unsigned long'?
2. scanf() function worked for me, but not the fgets() function.

As I understand the size parameter in the fgets() function is the maximum size it can hold and not to be met necessarily (so if less size then ok), then why I wasn't able to use the fgets() function instead the scanf().

thanks.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Does that include `fgets`? If so, what input method _should_ you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first of your problem, [`sizeof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) return a value of type `size_t` which is often an alias for `unsigned long`, hence why the `"%lu"` format works. However, you should *not* use that format, instead you should be using `"%zu"` which is specified to have a `size_t` argument ([see e.g. this `printf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)).

As for your second question, you have to remember that [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) can *include* the newline (if it fits) in the string. You have to explicitly check for and remove it:

```
if (fgets(mytype1, sizeof(mytype1), stdin) != NULL)
{
    if (mytype1[strlen(mytype1) - 1] == '\n')  // Is the last character a newline?
        mytype1[strlen(mytype1) - 1] = '\0';  // Yes, change it to the string terminator
}
```

Comment: actually the `fgets()` works fine if I typed `double` at the terminal, where the `int` parameter of the `fgets()` == 7 (6 +1) which meets the specified `int` in the `double` statement, so apparently it works  only when both `int` parameters are equal in mytype1 and mytype3.

Comment: @BasemHegazy Yes, entering `"double"` works because it's *six* characters then the seventh is the string terminator. It can't fit the newline inside the buffer size you provided. Any input shorter than six characters will include the newline-

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Just edit the code in your answer, so it's one `=` in the assignment statement `mytype1[strlen(mytype1) - 1] == '\0';`

Comment: @BasemHegazy Damn you copy-paste! :)